# Passing a function as prop in react native react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props, react-navigation-v5

Hi I want to add a function to record the value of input and want to use it in all components and input is in another component and I want to pass a function from App.js to that component but it does not work  please help me out \

Please note that the function should be in the App.js passed to Component.js through a Navigator

```js
//App.JS


import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {
  Text,
  Link,
  HStack,
  Center,
  Heading,
  Switch,
  useColorMode,
  NativeBaseProvider,
  extendTheme,
  VStack,
  Box,
} from "native-base";
import NativeBaseIcon from "./components/NativeBaseIcon";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from "./Comp/HomeScreen";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Location from "./Comp/Location";

export default function App() {
  const [api, setapi] = useState(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)

  const api_1 = () => {
    setapi(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_2)
  }
  const api_2 = () => {
    setapi(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_3)
   
  }

  const [value, setvalue] = useState("London")
    const handlechange = (e) => {
        setvalue(e.target.value)
        console.log('value :>> ', value);
    }
  const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>

        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen  name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen initialParams={{value:value, change:handlechange}}   name="Location"  component={Location} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

//Component.js
import { Center, Input, Text } from 'native-base'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
import BG from "./Img/BG.png"

export default function Location({ navigation, route }) {
    //  const [value, setvalue] = useState("London")
    //  const handlechange = (e) => {
    //      setvalue(e.target.value)
    //      console.log('value :>> ', value);
    //  }
    const { change, value } = route.params;
    return (
        <ImageBackground source={BG}>
            <Center minH={"100vh"} w={"90vw"} alignSelf={"center"} alignContent={"center"}>
                <Input color={"white"} size="xl" onChange={change} variant="rounded" placeholder="Enter Location" />
                <Text color={"white"}></Text>
            </Center>

        </ImageBackground>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: can you share a working expo snack will check there